# Tensorflow Object Detection API with GPU Installation

Tags: python, pip, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I wanted to try creating an object detection model, so I followed [this official tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html). Everything worked fine. I could use GPU, and no error while I was installing COCO API. As I checked by "Verify the installation" step in the tutorial.

"Verify the installation" tell me to run below code

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

case 1: If I can not use GPU, I would see a print-out similar to the one bellow

```
2020-06-22 19:20:32.614181: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-06-22 19:20:32.620571: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2020-06-22 19:20:35.027232: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-06-22 19:20:35.060549: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1070 Ti computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.683GHz coreCount: 19 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 238.66GiB/s
2020-06-22 19:20:35.074967: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-06-22 19:20:35.084458: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_10.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_10.dll not found
2020-06-22 19:20:35.094112: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2020-06-22 19:20:35.103571: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2020-06-22 19:20:35.113102: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found
2020-06-22 19:20:35.123242: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_10.dll not found
2020-06-22 19:20:35.140987: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-06-22 19:20:35.146285: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1598] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2020-06-22 19:20:35.162173: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-06-22 19:20:35.178588: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x15140db6390 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-06-22 19:20:35.185082: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-06-22 19:20:35.191117: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-06-22 19:20:35.196815: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]
tf.Tensor(1620.5817, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

case 2: If it can found my GPU, print-out would be like below.

```
2020-06-22 20:24:31.355541: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.650692: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.686846: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1070 Ti computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.683GHz coreCount: 19 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 238.66GiB/s
2020-06-22 20:24:33.697234: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.747540: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.787573: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.810063: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.841474: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.862787: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.907318: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.913612: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-06-22 20:24:33.918093: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-06-22 20:24:33.932784: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x2382acc1c40 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-06-22 20:24:33.939473: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-06-22 20:24:33.944570: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1070 Ti computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.683GHz coreCount: 19 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 238.66GiB/s
2020-06-22 20:24:33.953910: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.958772: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.963656: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.968210: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.973389: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.978058: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.983547: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-06-22 20:24:33.990380: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-06-22 20:24:35.338596: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-06-22 20:24:35.344643: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0
2020-06-22 20:24:35.348795: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N
2020-06-22 20:24:35.353853: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6284 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2020-06-22 20:24:35.369758: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x2384aa9f820 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-06-22 20:24:35.376320: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1070 Ti, Compute Capability 6.1
tf.Tensor(122.478485, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

**When I tried to install the Object Detection API (last step), I can installed it successfully, but I cannot use GPU anymore (print-out show as case 1 I write above).**

"Install the Object Detection API" step tell me to install packages from command below

```
python -m pip install .
```

setup.py file

```
"""Setup script for object_detection with TF2.0."""
import os
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

# Note: adding apache-beam to required packages causes conflict with
# tf-models-offical requirements. These packages request for incompatible
# oauth2client package.
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    # Required for apache-beam with PY3
    'avro-python3',
    'apache-beam',
    'pillow',
    'lxml',
    'matplotlib',
    'Cython',
    'contextlib2',
    'tf-slim',
    'six',
    'pycocotools',
    'lvis',
    'scipy',
    'pandas',
    'tf-models-official'
]

setup(
    name='object_detection',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=(
        [p for p in find_packages() if p.startswith('object_detection')] +
        find_packages(where=os.path.join('.', 'slim'))),
    package_dir={
        'datasets': os.path.join('slim', 'datasets'),
        'nets': os.path.join('slim', 'nets'),
        'preprocessing': os.path.join('slim', 'preprocessing'),
        'deployment': os.path.join('slim', 'deployment'),
        'scripts': os.path.join('slim', 'scripts'),
    },
    description='Tensorflow Object Detection Library',
    python_requires='>3.6',
)
```

I notice that version of tensorflow was changed (from 2.2.0 to 2.4.0) after I installed the Object Detection API. Plus, my newly created conda env which installed tensorflow 2.2.0 could use GPU normally. Does the version of tensorflow make me cannot use GPU? **If so, how do I install packages without changing the version of the other packages**.

Comment: " but I cannot use GPU anymore." What does this mean? Can you show any logs/ warns etc

Comment: @papaya Thanks for your asking. I just updated my post to clarify this confusion. I checked it by the print-out, and it shown as case 1 in my post.

Comment: `If I'm guessing right, in tf2.4 the cuda version required is 11.0` Perhaps this is why you aren't able to get it running?  Based on your logs you have `cuda 10.1` which works for tf2.2. Let me know this helps your question

Comment: @papaya Thank you so much! It's work! At first, I didn't want to change CUDA's version because the tutorial said it should be version 10.1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tensorflow 2.2` uses `CUDA 10.1` but after running the object-detection api your tensorflow is getting updated to 2.4, at which point GPU no longer is used to run the default test program.

This is because, `Tensorflow 2.4.0` uses `CUDA 11.0`. If you simply update cuda to the right version, you will have this working.